# how to make the html div responsive to the screen resolution

Tags: html, css, angular, responsive

All, new to web development, I am trying to create a login page. It works correctly for 1400*765 but how to make to responsive for all screen. Please help me on this.. Sorry for the basic question here again.

I have three images login.png, bck.png and icon.png. So bck.png is background image, login.png is designed box and icon.png is icon which along with login.png.

```css
.login-wrapper {
  top: 154px;
  left: 528px;
  width: 385px;
  height: 509px;
  background: url('../../assets/login.png') 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}

.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('../../assets/bck.png') 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  color: white;
  top: -0.000244140625px;
  left: 0.0009765625px;
  position: fixed;
}

.icon {
  background: url('../../assets/icon.png') 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 90px;
  left: 656px;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  position: fixed;
}

.example-full-width {
  top: 328px;
  left: 568px;
  width: 304px;
  height: 52px;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
}

.example-full-width1 {
  top: 409px;
  left: 568px;
  width: 304px;
  height: 52px;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
}

.btn-block {
  top: 516px;
  left: 569px;
  width: 304px;
  height: 60px;
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #FF80A9 0%, #C93C6A 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
}

.h1 {
  top: 228px;
  left: 652px;
  width: 139px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: left;
  font: Heavy 25px/34px Avenir;
  letter-spacing: 8.05px;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
}

.h2 {
  top: 264px;
  left: 670px;
  width: 104px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  font: Black 18px/25px Avenir;
  letter-spacing: 2.63px;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
<div class='icon'></div>
<div class="login-wrapper">

  <div class="box">
    <mat-card-header>
      <h1 class='h1'>CONFIG</h1>
      <h2 class="h2">SERVICES</h2>
    </mat-card-header>

    <form class="example-form">
      <mat-card-content>
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Email">
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width1">
          <input matInput placeholder="Password">
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-card-content>
      <button mat-stroked-button color=#C93C6A class="btn-block">Log in</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check the basics of [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media queries to make your website responsive to all screens

For example:

`@media (max-width: 1600px) {
// your CSS codes
}`

Comment: but the position of other CSS images and components are not been responsive .. only the background image is becoming responsive. by css media i tried it

Answer (score 0):

There really are tons of ways for you to make a website more responsive.

You may want to read into
[CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp). They let you define style rules only applicable for a certain screen size.

Something like this:

```
/* normal styling (e.g. mobile) */
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  /* extra styling for desktop */
}
```

Comment: I recommend using a framework that handles responsive design. I used Bootstrap, but have changed to Creator. If you want to code it yourself look at 'css media queries'